# struct member initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a defined struct like this one:

```
typedef struct tag_GLOBAL_VAR
{
    int array1[4];
    int array2[5];
    .......
    int array20[40];
 }GLOBAL_VAR;
```

This structure is used to define a variable in some class:

```
GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
```

and then used in another class like this:

```
extern GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;

class constructor;

class destructor;

int class::Start()
{
     //g_GlobalVar.array1 = {1,2,3,4};
     //g_GlobalVar.array4 = {1,2,3};
     some code;
 }
```

My problem is that i can't initialize (commented lines) those 2 arrays like that, i get a `error C2059: syntax error : '{'` from VS. Why is this wrong and which is the solution to do it?

Comment: i don't really know...i use vs2008 with no SP.

Comment: A little off-topic, but consider using containers instead of arrays

Comment: So you are not using C++11. This is not possible with vs2008 and I am not sure if it is possible even in vs2010.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: The fact that he uses a typedef construct for his struct might be a hint that he wants to share this struct with C code. In which case using a container is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize the values of an array in such way after its declaration. Such syntax is only possible when you declare and set an array at once, like this:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

In all other places, you will have to set every element.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong because this is not initialization, but setting a new value. Your arrays are already initialized when you declared g_GlobalVar.

I see 2 solution: A) to create new arrays, initialize them like you trying to do and copy new array in you arrays in loops; B) to set each entry of each array separately.

Answer (score 2):

The special array initializer syntax is only available at, you guessed it, array initialization. At other times, you have to set the values one by one.

However, struct assignment (combined with initializers) allows for a shortcut, like this:

```
GLOBAL_VAR temporary = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
g_GlobalVar = temporary;
```

Other solutions include using `memcpy`:

```
int temp1[] = {1,2,3,4};
memcpy(g_GlobalVar.array1, temp1, sizeof temp1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to initialize several member arrays at once, you may do following

```
const GLOBAL_VAR my_const = {{1,2,3,4}, {}, {}, {1,2,3}};  
g_GlobalVar = my_const;
```

Comment: i've seen this approach somewhere else, and by what i understand about arrays, this will initialize the first 2 arrays with those values, and the rest with `0`. What if i want to initialize the 22nd and 24th array of a struct? i will need to initialize all the first 24 arrays of the struct, right?

Comment: @MRM: Yes, you have to initialize all arrays, at least with {}.

Comment: There isn't an array assignment in C++ that you seem to use in your latter example.

Answer (score 0):

The in-place init ({...}) is only supported in C++11 for PODs.